# Deleting a Collection with NHibernate Using the Criteria API

Tags: nhibernate

I think I know what the answer to this question is probably going to be, but I thought I'd go ahead and ask it anyway.

It appears that within NHibernate if I do something like this:

```
IList<Customer> customers = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Customer))
                                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Name", "Steve")
                                .List<Customer>();
```

And I want to then delete that list of customers. From what I can tell the only way to do it is like this:

```
foreach(var customer in customers)
{
    Session.Delete(customer);
}
```

But what I'm wondering is if there's any way I can just go:

```
Session.Delete(customers);
```

And delete the entire collection with a single call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with Criteria, but it's easy to do with HQL:

```
session.CreateQuery("delete Customer customer where customer in (:customers)")
       .SetParameterList("customers", customers.ToArray())
       .ExecuteUpdate();
```

But you don't need to load them. You can also do it in one shot:

```
session.CreateQuery("delete Customer where Name = 'Steve'")
       .ExecuteUpdate();
```